# Possible scenarios when product price html should be rendered or not in frontend grid or list

Tags: price, frontend, magento-2.1.3

I would like to know what are the possible **scenarios** when **product price** html should be rendered for a product and if it's not rendered then **why** ?

The one that is know is when product is **out of stock** or say not **saleable**.
Need to figure out the rest.

One of my case is that **prices** are **not** getting **rendered** for a product in **recently viewed products grid**. I tried to debug the function **getProductPriceHtml()** but could not find any solution yet.

I checked in **default magento2.1.3 with sample data** , its **displaying** prices html for **recently** viewed products. So why not in my case ?

The html is something like this :

```
<div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="428">
    <span class="old-price">


<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label"></span>
        <span id="old-price-428" data-price-amount="500" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
        <span class="price">RS 500.00</span>    </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="special-price">


<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label"></span>
        <span id="product-price-428" data-price-amount="300" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
        <span class="price">RS 300.00</span>    </span>
        </span>
    </span>
                    <span class="special-discount">40% Off</span>



</div>
```

Let me know the possible causes for my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem for my case :

The template that I used i.e **viewed_grid.phtml** was **overridden** in my **theme** where **price** related code was **removed**. I was sort of not looking into it as I thought the problem cannot be in theme section.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" page_size="5" template="widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}
```

But I would still like to know if there are any more cases where price html is not rendered and as the answer in not yet complete, I am not accepting it for now.